# Como optimizar función de sumar días a una fecha en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

Conseguí la siguiente función en Javascript para sumarle días a una fecha, pero me parece que hace muchos pasos innecesarios, como podría optimizarla?

```
function MostrarFechaT() {
        var d = document.getElementById('dias').value;
        if (d == 0) {
            alert("No has ingresado el n\u00famero de d\u00edas")
            var fechaFinal = "";
        } else {
            var Fecha = new Date();
            var sFecha = (Fecha.getDate() + "-" + (Fecha.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + Fecha.getFullYear());
            var sep = sFecha.indexOf('-') != -1 ? '-' : '-';
            var aFecha = sFecha.split(sep);
            var fecha_array = aFecha[2] + '-' + aFecha[1] + '-' + aFecha[0];
            fecha = new Date(fecha_array);
            fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + parseInt(d));
            var anno = fecha.getFullYear();
            var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
            var dia = fecha.getDate();
            mes = (mes < 10) ? ("0" + mes) : mes;
            dia = (dia < 10) ? ("0" + dia) : dia;
            var fechaFinal = (dia + sep + mes + sep + anno);
            var fechaFinalPasar = (anno + sep + mes + sep + dia);
            document.getElementById("fecha_termino").value = fechaFinal;
            document.getElementById("valor_fechatermino").value = fechaFinalPasar;
            document.getElementById("restablecer").hidden = false;
        }
    }
```

---

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" name="dias" id="dias" size="1" maxlength="2" onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event);" onchange="MostrarFechaT();comprobarAmplitud();" onpaste="return false" oncopy="return false" disabled>
<input type="text" name="fecha_inicio" value="<?php echo $fecha=date('d-m-Y') ?>" readonly disabled id="fecha_inicio"> 
<input type="text" name="valor_fechainicio" value="<?php echo $fecha=date('Y-m-d') ?>" >                                 
<input type="text" name="fecha_termino" readonly id="fecha_termino"> 
<input type="text" name="valor_fechatermino" id="valor_fechatermino">
```

Funcion adaptada a la respuesta de @OscarGarcia:

```
function MostrarFechaT() {
  var numero = document.getElementById("dias");
  var resultado = document.getElementById("fecha_termino");
  var resultado_pasar = document.getElementById("valor_fechatermino");
  var hoy = new Date();
  alert(hoy);
  var dias = parseInt(numero.value);
  alert(dias);
  var calculado = new Date();
  alert(calculado);
  calculado.setDate(hoy.getDate() + dias);
  resultado = calculado.getDay() + '-' + calculado.getMonth() + '-' + calculado.getFullYear();
  resultado_pasar = calculado.getFullYear() + '-' + calculado.getMonth() + '-' + calculado.getDay();
  document.getElementById("fecha_termino").value = resultado;
  document.getElementById("valor_fechatermino").value = resultado_pasar;
  document.getElementById("restablecer").hidden = false;
}
```

Problema actual:

Con la fecha actual 5-5-17 si sumo 1 dia devuelve: 6-4-17 si sumo 2 deveulve 0-4-17

Comment: no puedes utilizar una libreria? como https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @JackNavaRow tengo esa funcion porque fue la unica que encontre y me funciono, pero me parece que hace muchos pasos inncesarios

Comment: ¿Puedo aportarte una solución sin reutilizar tu código? Lo que quieres es simplemente agregar al día actual el número de días indicado en un formulario, ¿no?

Comment: Una librería como momentjs reducirá el tamaño del código de esa función... pero añadiría 17-64 KB más a la página. Con lo que la optimización sería relativa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar la siguiente conversión de fechas para sumar el número de días deseado usando el objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date):

```js
var numero = document.getElementById("numero");
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
function calcular() {
  var hoy = new Date();
  var dias = parseInt(numero.value);
  var calculado = new Date();
  calculado.setDate(
    hoy.getDate() + dias
  );
  resultado.innerText = calculado.getDate() + '/' +
    (calculado.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + calculado.getFullYear() +
    ' -- ' + calculado.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (calculado.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + calculado.getDate();
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="number" id="numero" min="0" max="120" value="0" />
  <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

Lo que hacemos es sacar partido de la funcionalidad que ofrece [`Date.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) que incrementa o decrementa automáticamente el mes (y el año) si pasamos por debajo de 1 o por encima del número de días del mes.

Comment: Quisiera obtener dos formatos de fecha Dia-Mes-Año y Año-Mes-ia como hago?

Comment: Modifica el orden en el que lo agrego a la cadena. Te he agregado un ejemplo en mi edición.

Comment: Gracias, si meto los var numero y resultado dentro de la funcion? coje los datos?, porque me esta dando alerts(para verificar) pero no calcula nada

Comment: ¡Claro! Puedes meterlo dentro de la función sin ningún problema.

Comment: El problema creo que esta en el innerText usare documentGet

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código de cómo lo has hecho?

Comment: Por cierto puse agregar 2 dias y salio esta fecha 0-4-2017

Comment: ¿Qué navegador usas? Estoy en móvil y mis posibilidades de edición son limitadas (por eso no he podido basarme en tu código).

Comment: Agregue la modificacion, uso google chrome la ultima version

Comment: Cuando muestro el valor calculado sale bien la fecha, pero al pasarla a respuesta sale mala, por el formato, modificala :)

Comment: Hecho, error mío, hay que usar `getDate()` para obtener el día, por las prisas puse `getDay()`.

Comment: Ya lo cambie pero sigue mostrando 6-4-17 en vez de 6-5-17

Comment: Hay que sumar uno https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getMonth

Comment: sip, porque las fechas tienen formato 0(enero) y 11(diciembre)

Comment: Estoy a dos manos, con la app de stackoverflow para responderte y con chrome para Android (con "ver como en ordenador" activado) para hacer las pruebas con el editor de código :'( no sé cómo no me di cuenta que ya estamos en el mes 5 x') siento haberte hecho perder tiempo con pruebas, normalmente suelo ser más concienzudo.

Comment: jajajaja tranquilo me sirvio tu respuesta, modificala para que sirva de ayuda al resto de las personas :)

Comment: Creo que ya la edité. Ojalá algún día mejoren la aplicación del móvil y permita usar el editor de HTML/CSS/JS en ella, sería una pasada :) PD: Ahora que leo con más detenimiento tu código, veo que has estado muy cerca de la solución, supongo que te fallaba lo del `new Date(fecha_array)`. ¿No?

Comment: Esa funcion servia pero era muy dificil de entender y el sistema NO es mi, yo si la entendia,era dificil porque obtenías la fecha en formato date, la dividias, creabas un separador, luego hacias un splice, luego la volvias string, luego sumabas, luego ordenabas luego armabas el el string y lo pasabas a array y luego bla bla bla, nanaaaaaa mucho trabajon

Answer (score 4):

Para saber qué pasos eliminar habría que saber qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente.

Si lo único que quieres es tener una función que sume días a una fecha:

```js
function sumDias(fecha, numDias){
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + numDias);
  return fecha;
}

$('#NumDias').on('keyup', function(){
   var numDias = parseInt($('#NumDias').val());
   if (isNaN(numDias)) { 
    $('#Resultado').text('');
    return; 
   }
   var fechaActual = new Date();
   var fechaCalculada = sumDias(fechaActual, numDias);
   $('#Resultado').text(fechaCalculada.toLocaleDateString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nº días: <input type="numeric" id="NumDias" />

<br/><br/>

Resultado: <span id="Resultado"></span>
```

Comment: Te explico otra cosa, la fecha actual es generada en un campo y esa fecha se le suma el dia, una vez cambien el valor se generar la fecha, en formato año-mes-dia para que se guarde en SQL y dia-mes y año para verlo en el formulario

Comment: Tengo un efecto change en los dias

Comment: Para que cambie la fecha mientras escribes puedes utilizar el evento keyup

Comment: y para generar la fecha con el otro formato ? Dia-Mes-Año, porque ese lo genera en formato que se guarda en SQL, pero quiero tambien mostrarlo e la otra menra