# Como formatear una fecha de tipo Date() y sumarle n cantidad de dias dependiendo de un formato ingresado?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buenas tardes a todos,

Quisiera su valiosa ayuda para poder hacer una funcion que me sume los dias a fecha cualquiera ingresada por el usuario, llevo un buen rato ya buscando en web pero lo unico que me aparece es sumarle dias a la fecha actual,[image]

Dando click al datepicker del input me sume 122 o 125 dias dependiendo que duracion tiene el formato. El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero capturar la fecha que el usuario ingreso me aparece Tue Mar 24 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time) entonces cuando quiero formatear la fecha me dice que la funcion getDate(_) no es valida

Mi codigo al momento es este:

```js
function sumDias(fecha, numDias) {
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + numDias);
  return fecha;
};

function zero(n) {
  return (n > 9 ? '' : '0') + n;
};

$("#date1_record").on("change", function() {
  var id_format = $("#id_format_record").val();
  var id_format_array = id_format.split('-');
  var id_format = id_format_array[1];
  var numDias = parseInt(id_format);
  alert(numDias);
  if (isNaN(numDias)) {
    $('#date2_record').text('');
    return;
  }
  var fecha = document.getElementById('date1_record').value;
  var fechaActual = new Date(fecha);
  //var fechaActual = fechaActual0.getFullYear() + "-" + zero(fechaActual0.getMonth()+1) + "-" + zero(fechaActual0.getDate());
  alert(fechaActual);
  var fechaCalculada = sumDias(fechaActual, numDias);
  $('#date2_record').text(fechaCalculada.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label for="date1_record" title="Fecha Ingreso"><h6><strong>*Fecha Inicio</strong></h6></label>
  <input id="date1_record" type="text" class="form-control date" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label for="date2_record" title="Fecha Ingreso"><h6><strong>*Fecha Final</strong></h6></label>
  <input id="date2_record" type="text" class="form-control date" style="margin-bottom: 10px" disabled>
</div>
```

[image: Valor id_format_record]

[image: Valor date1_record]

Su ayuda porfavor...!!

Comment: Mi pregunta toma como parametro el valor de otro campo, ya que hago una concatenacion con el id y duracion del formato,

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste adaptar la solución que se propuso y aceptó para la otra pregunta?

Comment: Esta otra pregunta también es sobre sumar días a una fecha https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67659/65

Comment: Hola buenas noches, si ya intente adaptar la solucion propuesta pero no me funciono o en algun lado lo hice mal.

Comment: No funciona ¿pero que es lo que pasa o deja de pasar? ¿Ocurre algún mensaje de error?

Comment: El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero capturar la fecha que el usuario ingreso me aparece Tue Mar 24 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time) entonces cuando quiero formatear la fecha me dice que la funcion getDate(_) no es valida

Comment: Ok Listo.. muchas Gracias Ruben

Comment: otra cosa que falta es que indiques el framework o librerías que usas además de jQuery

Comment: Solamamente estoy usando jquery (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js) para realizar ese calculo, y datepicker

Comment: Pues algo falta ya que al hacer clic en "Ejecutar" no se muestra el datepicker

Comment: Otra cosa que le falta a tu código es el elemento con id "id_format_record". Cabe mencionar que es mejor indicar el mensaje textual de error.

Comment: El id format record es la duracion de formato, ahi me captura el int 122 o 125 que son los dias de duracion

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para que lo incluyas o retira las sentencias que lo requieren para que el código se pueda ejecutar.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta y pondre las capturaas de los valores de id format y sum dias que me esta capturando

Comment: si disculpe, ya edite la pregunta....

Comment: Edité mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregué a al código del OP el elemento id_format_record como sugerí en un comentario. Al menos en Stack Snippet con esto funciona correctamente.

- El número de días debe ingresarse en forma n-n, ejemplo 2-122
- La fecha de inicio debe ingresarse en forma yyyy-mm-dd ejemplo 2018-03-24

```js
function sumDias(fecha, numDias) {
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + numDias);
  return fecha;
};

function zero(n) {
  return (n > 9 ? '' : '0') + n;
};

$("#date1_record").on("change", function() {
  var id_format = $("#id_format_record").val();
  var id_format_array = id_format.split('-');
  var id_format = id_format_array[1];
  var numDias = parseInt(id_format);
  alert(numDias);
  if (isNaN(numDias)) {
    $('#date2_record').text('');
    return;
  }
  var fecha = document.getElementById('date1_record').value;
  var fechaActual = new Date(fecha);
  //var fechaActual = fechaActual0.getFullYear() + "-" + zero(fechaActual0.getMonth()+1) + "-" + zero(fechaActual0.getDate());
  alert(fechaActual);
  var fechaCalculada = sumDias(fechaActual, numDias);
  $('#date2_record').text(fechaCalculada.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label for="id_format_record" title="Fecha Ingreso"><h6><strong>*Días</strong></h6></label>
  <input id="id_format_record" type="text" class="form-control date" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label for="date1_record" title="Fecha Ingreso"><h6><strong>*Fecha Inicio</strong></h6></label>
  <input id="date1_record" type="text" class="form-control date" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label for="date2_record" title="Fecha Ingreso"><h6><strong>*Fecha Final</strong></h6></label>
  <input id="date2_record" type="text" class="form-control date" style="margin-bottom: 10px" disabled>
</div>
```

---

**Respuesta inicial**

El problema es que tu código espera el número de días en formato
Si getDate no es válida, entonces el la variable fecha no hace referencia a un objeto de tipo fecha.

Usa `new Date()` para convertir la cadena a fecha. Ejemplo:

```js
var cadena = 'Tue Mar 24 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time)';
var fecha = new Date(cadena);
var numDias = 5;

console.info(sumDias(fecha,numDias));

function sumDias(fecha, numDias) {

  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + numDias);
  return fecha;
};
```

Comment: Pues el valor del input es de tipo estring me guarda 2018-03-12, por eso lo paso a valor tipo fecha: var fecha = document.getElementById('date1_record').value;
  var fechaActual = new Date(fecha);

Comment: @Khriz01 si la solución de Rubén te sirvió (como indicas en tu respuesta), deberías marcarla como aceptada y opcionalmente darle un voto positivo. De ese modo, otros usuarios que tengan un error parecido, podrán encontrar la respuesta de manera más rápida. Lee [answer] y [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Lo acabo de resolver Ruben, muchas gracias por sus consejos y sugerencias, modifique el codigo y lo deje de esta manera

```
    function sumDias(fecha, numDias){
     fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + numDias);
     return fecha;
    };
    function zero(n) {
     return (n>9 ? '' : '0') + n;
   };
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#date1_record").on("change", function(){
    var id_format = $("#id_format_record").val();
    var id_format_array = id_format.split('-');
    var id_format = id_format_array[1];
    var numDias = parseInt(id_format);
    //alert(numDias);
     if (isNaN(numDias)) {
      $('#date2_record').text('');
      return;
     }
     var fecha = $("#date1_record").val();
     var fechaActual = new Date(fecha);
     //var fechaActual = fechaActual0.getFullYear() + "-" + 
     zero(fechaActual0.getMonth()+1) + "-" + zero(fechaActual0.getDate());
     //alert(fechaActual);
     var fechaCalculada = sumDias(fechaActual, numDias);
     var fechaCalculada2 = new Date(fechaCalculada);
     var fechaCalculada3 = fechaCalculada2.getFullYear() + "-" + 
     zero(fechaCalculada2.getMonth()+1) + "-" + 
     zero(fechaCalculada2.getDate());
     $('#date2_record').val(fechaCalculada3);
     });
```